# How does the spell Earthquake interact with a mounted PC, if the mount is knocked prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mounted-combat, prone

If you are on a mount and it is knocked prone, do you automatically get knocked prone too?

To set the scene, I am mounted on my Warhorse when an evil NPC casts **Earthquake** below where we stand. My Warhorse makes a saving throw but fails and is knocked prone.

Does this mean that I too would automatically be knocked prone? Would I need to make a separate saving throw against the spell? Or, do I need to do an Acrobatics check for instance to see if I can land on my feet?

I would appreciate responses with RAW or RAF.

Answer (score 13):

## You can use your reaction to dismount

The answer is in the Mounted Combat section of the Combat chapter:

> If your mount is knocked prone, you can use your reaction to dismount
> it as it falls and land on your feet. Otherwise, you are dismounted
> and fall prone in a space within 5 feet it. (PHB 198)

## You don't make a save vs the spell (this time)

This effect of the spell affects

> each creature on the ground in the area

which you are not, at the moment it happens. Your status changes as a result of it activating and thus it happens definitely *after* the effect is resolved.

Comment: @Medix2 True. I missed that sub-question. Thanks for pointing it out. Will edit.